# Batch move apt keys from trusted.gpg to folder, then add [signed-by=...] as needed

Tags: debian, ubuntu, apt, gpg

There's been this annoying deprecation of `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg`, even though putting the keys into `trusted.gpg.d/` (which suppresses `apt update` warnings) doesn't actually help with security at all (for that, you would need `deb [signed-by=...]` entries everywhere). I've seen it first in Ubuntu 22.04.

Now, it looks like `apt` **knows** which key from `trusted.gpg` signs which `sources.list` `deb[-src]` entry, but (again annoyingly) refuses to tell. It's so much more useful to issue a vague warning like

```
W: https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/jammy-cran40/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
```

Of course, it won't make it easy on me and tell me which key in `trusted.gpg` signs it. Maybe there's a verbose option — I don't know.

I'm sure a lot of people have been through this. Yet apparently there's no script to automate moving the individual keys into a folder (e.g. `/usr/local/share/keyrings`) and adding `[signed-by=...]` to the relevant `sources.list[.d]` entries.

How would I go about this task? In particular, how do I **identify** which key signs which `deb[-src]` entry? And how do I **extract** an individual `one-key.gpg` from the `trusted.gpg` heap, so as to move it to a folder?

Answer (score 4):

I've adapted the [gist](https://gist.github.com/maxhq/7dadf55064aaadc4d9e5993f89fad7b0) mentioned in [Dinkum's answer](https://gist.github.com/maxhq/7dadf55064aaadc4d9e5993f89fad7b0) — resulting in [`migrate-apt-keys`](https://github.com/kstr0k/migrate-apt-keys). It fixes some things, like having multiple entries signed by different keys in a single `sources.list.d` file.

Important commands:

- `deb[-src]` entries have their keys in an `InRelease` or `Release.gpg` file under a URL constructed from the entry (see the code). Use `curl` or `wget` to download them.
- `gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring gnupg-ring:/path/to/file ...`: required to operate on a specific file unrelated to `~/.gnupg`. The filename must be a path, not a basename. Also, prefixing with `gnupg-ring:` implies the keyring format, which `apt` can handle, as opposed to the default keybox format
- `gpg --list-keys --with-colons --fixed-list-mode` generates machine-readable output

Answer (score -3):

Try this script out and see how you go https://gist.github.com/maxhq/7dadf55064aaadc4d9e5993f89fad7b0

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# DESCRIPTION
#   This script migrates from "apt-key" managed keys to "[signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/...]":
#    - loop through all lists in /etc/apt/sources.list.d
#      - read all lines with "deb..." that do not contain "[signed-by=]"
#      - download the GPG signature from the URL
#        - read the key ID from the signature
#        - download and saves the key using gpg
#      - add "[signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/...]" to the "deb..." line
#    - make a backup of the old .list file as .list.apt-key
#  After the migration you have to delete (or rename to be safe) /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d and
#  /etc/apt/trusted.gpg
#
# REQUIREMENTS
#   bash, perl, curl, gpg
#
# CAVEATS
#   This does not work e.g. for Anydesk as the Ubuntu keyserver returns an expired key.
#   But you can manually download the ASCII armored key and then run migrate-apt-keys.sh:
#     curl https://keys.anydesk.com/repos/DEB-GPG-KEY | gpg --dearmor > /usr/share/keyrings/anydesk-stable-archive-keyring.gpg
#   See: https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-users/2022-January/306500.html

set -e

for repo in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list; do
  sig_base=$(basename $repo | sed 's/\.list//')
  sig_file="/usr/share/keyrings/${sig_base}-archive-keyring.gpg"
  skip_repo=0
  new_repo=$(mktemp)

  migrated=0
  while read line; do
    # skip if no repo definition
    if grep -E -q -v '^deb(-src)?' <<<"$line"; then echo "$line" >> $new_repo; continue; fi
    # skip if already "signed-by"
    if grep -E -q 'signed-by' <<<"$line"; then echo "$line" >> $new_repo; continue; fi

    echo "$sig_base: >> $line"

    if [ -f $sig_file ]; then
      echo "$sig_base: key already exists - skipping download"
    else
      # assemble URL
      url=$(echo "$line" | perl -pe 's{^ (?:(?:deb|deb-src) \s+) (?: \[[^\]]+] \s+)? (\S+?)/? \s+ (\S+) \s+ .* }{ $suite=$2; "$1/".($suite=~m|/$|?$suite:"dists/$2/") }xe')
      echo "$sig_base: downloading $url"

      # download signature
      set +e
      sigfile=$(curl -s -f -L "${url}InRelease")
      if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        sigfile=$(curl -s -f -L "${url}Release.gpg")
        if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then echo "$sig_base: URL ${url}[InRelease|Release.gpg] not found"; exit 1; fi
      fi
      set -e

      # read key ID from signature
      keyid=$(echo "$sigfile" | gpg --verify -vv 2>&1 | tr '\n' ' ' | sed -E 's/.*signature.*keyid ([0-9A-Z]+).*/\1/i')
      if [ -z "$keyid" ]; then echo "$sig_base: Could not find key id in signature"; exit 1; fi
      echo "$sig_base: key id = $keyid"

      # download key
      temp_sig=$(mktemp)
      gpg --quiet --no-default-keyring --keyring $temp_sig --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys $keyid
      expiry=$(gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring=$temp_sig --list-keys --with-colons --fixed-list-mode | grep pub | cut -d: -f7)
      if [[ ! -z "$expiry" && $expiry < $(date +"%s") ]]; then
        expiry_date=$(date -d "1970-01-01 UTC $expiry seconds" +"%Y-%m-%d %T %z")
        echo "$sig_base: SKIPPING migration - key expired on $expiry_date"
        skip_repo=1; break
      fi
      mv $temp_sig $sig_file
      chmod 0644 $sig_file
    fi

    echo "$line" \
     | SIG=$sig_file perl -pe 's{^ ((?:deb|deb-src) \s+) (?: \[ ([^\]]+) ] \s+ )? (.*) }{$1\[$2 signed-by=$ENV{SIG}\] $3}x' \
     >> $new_repo

    migrated=1
  done < <(cat "$repo")

  if [[ $skip_repo == 0 && $migrated == 1 ]]; then
    cp $repo $repo.apt-key
    # preserve permissions
    cat $new_repo > $repo
    echo "$sig_base: migration done"
  fi

  rm $new_repo
done
```

Comment: @terdon, not sure how copy/paste helps here, or addresses the criticisms initially leveled at this answer

Comment: @usretc what do you mean? This answer wasn't an answer, it was just a link. By including the script here, at least it now actually provides an answer.